# Handling SQL Server CE exceptions with Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to catch SQL Server CE exceptions with EF, however EF seems to swallow all exceptions including `UpdateException`, `SqlException` etc.

The only exception I could catch is the general `Exception`.

Is there a way to catch `SqlException` from SQL Server CE including the error numbers?

Comment: the similar question below: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189463/handles-sql-exception-from-entity-framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645233/entity-framework-4-2-getting-proper-database-errors?lq=1 this specific question did it for me actually,cheers.